# OR pattern matching

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I'm trying to use an OR pattern, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx):

```
let foo = function
    | Some (0, x) when x > 0 | None -> "bar"
    | _ -> "baz"
```

However, this gives a compiler error:

> error FS0010: Unexpected symbol '|' in pattern matching. Expected '->'
>   or other token.

What am I doing wrong? Does it have to do with the `when` guard?

Comment: Thanks, was looking for this. Strange that it's not been asked much. Scala does this more elegantly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `when` guard refers to a single case, regardless of how many patterns are combined. The cases need to be separated:

```
let foo = function
  | Some (0, x) when x > 0 -> "bar"
  | None -> "bar"
  | _ -> "baz"
```

For that reason, it may be better to factor out the return value, so a possibly complex expression isn't repeated:

```
let foo value =
  let ret = "bar"
  match value with
  | Some (0, x) when x > 0 -> ret
  | None -> ret
  | _ -> "baz"
```

Using an active pattern is another way to avoid such repetition:

```
let (|Bar|_|) = function
  | Some(0, x) when x > 0 -> Some()
  | None -> Some()
  | _ -> None

let foo = function
  | Bar -> "bar"
  | _ -> "baz"
```

Comment: The active pattern is also much cleaner and allows you to build up compositionally.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need two separate match cases there because the two cases bind different sets of variables (`x` and nothing, respectively):

```
| Some(0, x) when x>0 -> "bar"
| None -> "bar"
```

Answer (score 2):

A nice trick I sometime use when you want to guard only specific bindings of a label, in a very complex pattern, is to use my own active patterns and the `&` (`and`) pattern operator:

```
let (|GreaterThan|_|) lowerLimit n =
    if n > lowerLimit then Some () else None

let (|LesserThan|_|) upperLimit n =
    if n < upperLimit then Some () else None

let (|GreaterOETo|_|) lowerLimit n =
    if n >= lowerLimit then Some () else None

let (|LesserOETo|_|) upperLimit n =
    if n <= upperLimit then Some () else None

let (|InRange|_|) (lowerLimit, upperLimit) n =
    if n >= lowerLimit && n <= upperLimit then Some () else None

let (|Even|Odd|) n =
    if n % 2 = 0 then
        Even (n / 2)
    else
        Odd (n / 2)

type Union =
    | A of int
    | B of int
    | A' of int

let getSpecialCases = function
    | A (Even (x & GreaterThan 4 & LesserOETo 16))
    | A (Odd (x & GreaterThan 0))
    | B (x & LesserOETo 0)
    | A' (Even (x & InRange (5, 16)))
    | A' (Odd (x & GreaterThan 0)) -> Some x
    | _ -> None
```

And of course you can just make a function to active pattern wrapper:

```
let (|P|_|) pred x =
    if pred x then Some () else None

let ``match`` = function
    | Even (x & pred (fun x -> x >= 7 && x <= 54)) -> Some x
    | _ -> None
```